# Nifi:transfer relationship not specified

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I want to  update xml data  and  write it in  flowfile1  but  for  some  reason my  ExecuteScript  processor  can't  specify  transfer relationship   here  is  my  code,  **what  should  i  change   to  make  this  task?**:
Is  it  possbile  that   my  code  inside  session.write can't  cast  xml  data  to  ByteArray and  can't write  this in  flowfile content? ( but it  doesn't  throw  exception)

```
flowFile1 = session.putAttribute(flowFile1, "filename", "conf.xml");

               session.write(flowFile1, new StreamCallback() {
                @Override
                public void process(InputStream inputStream1, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
                     TransformerFactory transformerFactory1 = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                        Transformer transformer1 = null;
                        try {
                            transformer1= transformerFactory1.newTransformer();
                        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    DOMSource source1 = new DOMSource(doc);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(bos1);


                    try {
                        transformer1.transform(source1, result);
                    } catch (TransformerException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    byte[] array1 = bos1.toByteArray();
                    outputStream.write(array1);
                }

            });

            if(flowFile1!=null){

            session.transfer(flowFile1, REL_SUCCESS);
            }
            else{
            session.transfer(flowFile1, REL_FAILURE);

            }

        }catch (OverlappingFileLockException e) {
            lock.release();


        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Thread.sleep(5000);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {


            lock.release();
            ini.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

session.write() returns a reference to a newer version of the flow file, but you are not storing it or transferring it. Later on, you end up trying to transfer a version that is not the latest. Try adding "flowFile1 = " to the beginning of your session.write() statement.